# How to save the text content of a button clicked to a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, I am trying to save the text content of a button clicked to a variable and I know its possible but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
<div class="keyrow">
<button>q</button>  
<button>w</button>  
<button>e</button>  
<button>r</button>
<button>t</button>  
<button>y</button>  
<button>u</button>  
<button>i</button>
<button>o</button>  
<button>p</button>
</div>
```

I was thinking of something like this

`let keypress = document.querySelector('.keyrow').onclick;`

`keypress = keypress.textContent`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.keyrow').onclick = function(event) {
  var a = event.target.innerHTML;
  console.log(a);

}
```

```html
<div class="keyrow">
<button>q</button>  
<button>w</button>  
<button>e</button>  
<button>r</button>
<button>t</button>  
<button>y</button>  
<button>u</button>  
<button>i</button>
<button>o</button>  
<button>p</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your variable is q for q, add this.

```
<button onclick="saveVariable(q);" id="q">q</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 var saveletter;
function saveVariable(letter){
 saveletter=letter;
console.log(saveletter)
}
```

Also, let isn't var.
Change the parameter for the function to whatever you need to save to a variable.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @karthick-s is better but will leave my answer here in case you want to explore further.

Try this one:

```
    // Loop through all buttons inside keyrow
    document.querySelectorAll('.keyrow button').forEach((button) => {
        // Add listener to click event on all of those button
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              console.log(event.target.textContent); // content of the button - you can do anything with this here.
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = document.getElementById("keyro");
let vari;
obj.addEventListener('click',function(event){
   vari  = event.target.textContent;
   alert(vari);
});
```

```html
<div class="keyrow" id="keyro">
<button>q</button>  
<button>w</button>  
<button>e</button>  
<button>r</button>
<button>t</button>  
<button>y</button>  
<button>u</button>  
<button>i</button>
<button>o</button>  
<button>p</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var bb = document.querySelectorAll('.keyrow > button');
    for(let i=0;i<bb.length;i++) {
    bb[i].onclick = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value)
    }
    }
```